# Roll back commit without force push

Tags: git, github

I wish to roll back a commit in a repo that can't force push. Is it possible to roll back a secondary branch, rename the `main` branch to something else, rename my secondary branch to `main`, then set the `main` branch to default? Would this have adverse affects to all of the forks (given no one has unfinshed/unmerged work on `main`)? Would there be big problems one everyone's`main` branch when they pull the latest from upstream, or would it propperly drop the last commit?

Comment: do you want to roll back the commit (so see the commit and another one cancelling the modification) or do you want to delete it ?

Comment: You're going to have to ask the other people who use the history you want to truncate. If it's not going to cause them problems then you can find a way to do it. If it is, or if you can't reach them all, then your problem doesn't really have anything to do with Git.

Comment: Why can't you simply do a revert commit?

Comment: Hi @Ôrel, I would prefer to delete the commit, but a roll back would work if that isn't possible. jthill I think its safe to asssume right now that everyone's main branch is synced with the upstream main as it was before the commit that I want to delete was made.

Comment: If nobody's relying on the history you want to forget then re-hanging labels to forget it is consequence-free, it's the right thing to do.

Comment: enabling force push time to clean the mess can be also a better way

Comment: @jthill, just to clarify, you are saying that if no one is relying on the commit I want to remove, then this method of renaming the branches is sound? I just need to rehang the labels?

Comment: refnames are just labels on commits, *any* act that winds up changing the commit a ref name refers to is rehanging the label. fetch, push, commit-on-a-branch, la la, they all rehang labels. I haven't tried it, and @Ôrel's suggestion of just enabling a force-push is more straightforward, but I think the little dance you cooked up should do the trick, yes.